# Running Python (Django Script)?

Tags: python, django

Php Scripts Can be Executed via Xampp or Wamp . But how do i execute Django Scripts on my PC for development Purpose?

I researched a bit but didn't found anything

Comment: Django doesn't work like PHP, There's no such thing as 'Django scripts' (other than management commands). Do the Django tutorial here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ and you will understand.

Comment: Oscar, Django is rather more modern (and more demanding) than CGI scripts from 10 or 15 years ago. I highly recommend hosting with a company that understands Django and supports it well. For my smaller Django customers (i.e. not on a dedicated server) I use Webfaction.com -- great prices, powerful machines that are not overloaded, and it is run by *serious* geeks. Oh, and I use the Django development server for everything except staging and production servers -- works great!

Comment: @Peter - he's asking how to run a script locally in a development environment. I'm not sure why he's gotten 4 close votes with a reason of "unclear what your asking", or the down votes. It seems like a good question to me (but I'm not a Django guy).

Answer (score 1):

django comes with its own development server, just go to a django project directory and type "python manage.py runserver"; when deploying to a shared hosting, your host should configure WSGI or FastCGI setup for Django.

If you're looking for some sort of standalone CGI scripts, unfortunately that method of execution is not recommended for django. However, if you configure Apache for CGI, you can write standalone *python* scripts to run as CGI script (minus the django part).

I suggest you go through the [installation guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/) and the Django tutorials ([1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/), [2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/), [3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/), [4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/)), it explains how to get started with development. Django works quite a bit differently than php.

Answer (score 0):

Review the docs on how to run a django dev server for your project:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

You usually will not have "django scripts". That is, self contained individual scripts that can be launched like any normal python process. They are part of a framework which must be served as a project.

That being said, you can also serve your django project just the same as php using apache and either uwsgi or fcgi

If you try following a getting started django tutorial they will always show you how to start a project, and then start the development server so that you can view it.

Comment: You mean, i wont be able to make standalone scripts like i do in php? with my normal shared lamp hosting?

Comment: @Kelton: no you cant. Django is a framework with many components. You design a project which maps many urls to various apps which contain models and views and templates. Its never a single script

Comment: You could write a Django url map that matched any URL ending in '.py', and the corresponding view looked for a file with that name in that path, then just imported the python file. That's essentially what PHP does, but without the URL mapping part of the configuration.

Comment: @Spacedman: Thats entirely not the same thing here. That means you are implementing a processor in django, needing a django project to execute it. At that point, you now have a django project to write a normal view. I actually don't even know why I am taking the time to address this comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Django components, then you'll want to create subprojects for each of them and register them in the main project directory. Think of everything as a component you can add to an existing project, though some make this easier than others.

An old but relevant example of how to facilitate subprojects and "pluggable apps": [Django, Pluggable Apps, and Code Re-Use](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/09/django_pluggable_apps_and_code.html)

When in doubt, reread tutorials. The Django Tutorial leaves much to be desired, but there are others. Lightbird has a decent selection relevant to what I think you're describing ([example of how to integrate user-registration](http://lightbird.net/dbe/forum3.html#user-registration)).

Edit: If you're just looking to run a standalone script, it's all Python code. If you rework the Django-specific pieces, any script can be run by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a web framework written in Python, just like CakePHP which is written in PHP. So in order to run Django, you need a proper environment.

> You mean, i wont be able to make standalone scripts like i do in php? with my normal shared lamp hosting?

No. Unless your host supports Python and you know how to properly configure your server settings with Django. Most of the normal `LMAP` is not capable of hosting Django at all.

Script is a very very bad choice of word at all time. You can write this PHP code and display it in the browser as long as you put the file under server's directory (such as Apache) and open it directly through a url (ex:  http://localhost:8000/hello.php)

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

You can write that too in Python, but not in that style, and you need a web module (you need to configure it so that it actually display on the browser, rather than prompting `oops, you want to download this file?`

For development purpose, Django is shipped with a development server. So go through the tutorials other have recommended so far. You can setuo Apache, Niginx with mod_wcgi if you want for production purpose. That's out of the scope of your question.

A quick look at your recent questions: I think you need to understand that Python is not PHP. It's purpose is not for web development specifically. Python is a general purpose programming language which is capable of doing many things (but that is not to say that PHP can't. It can be done, just not the purpose of PHP).